# Call ASP.net web service method inside succeeded callback function of another method in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, callback

Ok, here is my problem:

I have two web service methods which are invoked properly in asmx fashion and return a string:

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, 
    // using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class myClass : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string myMethod1()
        {
           //some code
           return ss1; // ss1 is my returned string
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string myMethod2(string s, string p, string x, string y)
        {
           //some code
           return ss2; // ss2 is my returned string
        }
```

All I want is calling these methods from javascript and get the proper string value and display the last returned value in alert window, to do so I use callback function in javascript:

```
<script>
function pressButton()
{
   myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod1(succeededCallBack1);

   function succeededCallBack1(strResponse1)
   {
      //some operation with strResponse1
      myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod2(s, p, x, y, succeededCallBack2);

      function succeededCallBack2(strResponse2)
      {
         alert(strResponse2);
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Now, I have successfully get the strResponse1 and do my operations with it, I also successfully call myMethod2 from javascript(I insert a break point inside this method and it is getting hit) and the ss2 string is set properly. The problem is the succededCallBack2 function is not called inside my script and I have no alert window. Where is the problem?

**[EDIT1]**

I have just changed my method call to :

```
  <script>
    function pressButton()
    {
       myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod1(succeededCallBack1);

       function succeededCallBack1(strResponse1)
       {
          //some operation with strResponse1
          myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod2(s, p, x, y, succeededCallBack2());

          function succeededCallBack2(strResponse2)
          {
             alert(strResponse2);
          }
       }
    }
    </script>
```

Now, I can see the alert window and obviously the `succeededCallBack2` function is called inside my script. Ok, the problem is the alert window displays `undefined` value. It means the `strResponse2` is not getting set. I insert a break point in `myMethod2` to see if it  properly runs and guess what, the alert window is displayed before the break point in `myMethod2` is getting hit. How on earth can it be possible?

Comment: Have you defined s, p, x, y (in the script) somewhere?

Comment: yes I have defined them, and when I check the method in debug mode they are successfully passed to method

Comment: Include the code for `myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod2` as that´s where your callback is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You have writen the second function inside the first function. Correct it as below.

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
  myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod1(succeededCallBack1);
  function succeededCallBack1(strResponse1)
  {
     //some operation with strResponse
     myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod2(s, p, x, y, succeededCallBack2);   
  }
  function succeededCallBack2(strResponse2)
  {
     alert(strResponse2);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That is the thing which I guess caused the problem, but the problem exists :(

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
myNameSpace.myClass.myMethod2(s, p, x, y, function(res) {
       alert(res);
   });
```

Comment: I changed it but have the same problem. I debug my script with this code and the res is 'undefined' unfortunately :(